# Add a background image to a connector in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jsplumb

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a background image to a connector.

My objective is to create something like this:
[image]

This way I could have an animated images in the background symbolizing the direction and type of the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible since the connection is made up of SVG object which itself acts as background image. You can try `dashstyle` option while tweaking paint-style and gradients to obtain appropriate arrow as shown in image. For more refer: [API DOC](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/paint-styles)

Sample Code:

```
jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle = {
    lineWidth: 4,
    strokeStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
    gradient:{
              stops:[[0,"green"], [1,"red"]]
        },
    dashstyle: "7"
};
```

Result:

[image: Sample Image]

**Note**: Remember to use `jsPlumb.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.SVG)` since dashstyle doesn't work with jsPlumb.CANVAS (by default it is SVG)